# In Node.js, why isn't my QR code being read correctly?

Tags: node.js, qr-code

I'm trying to use the following package:

https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR

with the following image:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const jsqr = require("jsqr");
const png = require("upng-js");
const Promise = require('bluebird');

async function run() {
    try {
        const data = png.decode(await fs.readFile("./qr.png"));
        const out = {
            data: png.toRGBA8(data),
            height: data.height,
            width: data.width,
          };

        const code = jsqr(out.data, out.width, out.height);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

run();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Malformed data passed to binarizer.
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: are you sure data is `Uint8ClampedArray` ?

Comment: Busy day... The "Malformed data passed to binarizer" error happens when height/width don't match up with the data you are passing. I might be wrong, but `toRGBA8` returns 4 channels (rgba) where only 3 channels (rgb) are expected.

Comment: A workaround for the problem is to write that image into a canvas, read it out again and oss that to jsqr.